# Problem with git

Tags: git, ssh, gitosis

I'm new to git.

I need to use public key to push changes from my repo.
How can I administer users ? If i want delete an user ?

Is The public key management the only way to administer a git system ?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use git over ssh. git relies on ssh "just working" but all user authentication / public key issues are solely handled by ssh and are not directly anything to do with git.

Comment: Please let us know what Git server you use. gitolite? gitosis? A file share?

Comment: @Alexander Groß  I use gitosis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the ssh protocol to access your git repo, then yes, you need to add a public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the user account managing said repos.

But ssh is hardly the only protocol available to access your repo: [see the Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html): a simple shared path (local protocol) can be enough at first (no server, no key, but also no authentication).

Note: as explained in this Gitolite man page "**[Gitolite without ssh](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/0f377a7679845e1db9e6ea0830da7d25ba4ecf07/doc/gitolite-without-ssh.mkd)**", Gitolite manages only **authorization**, not **authentication**.
You can use ssh for its authentication capabilities.